# Why does my time series plot look so weird?

Tags: r, csv, plot

Using this data: 
https://datamarket.com/data/set/22xh/monthly-returns-for-att-jan-1961-through-dec-1967#!ds=22xh&display=line

and this code

```
X<-read.csv("monthly-returns-for-att-jan-1961.csv") 

returns <-ts(X,frequency = 12,start= c(1965,1)) 

plot(returns, xlab => "month", ylab = "", main = "monthly-returns-for-att-jan-1961")
```

I get this plot

[image]

What is the upper plot supposed to be, and how would I get rid of it? Also, why is the y axis legend so strange?

Comment: Because you made a time series of two columns, `Month` and `Monthly returns ...`. If you expand the graph so that you don't get over-write on the y label, you'll see that the top is `Monthly`. Perhaps you meant `return <- ts(X[,2], ...)`?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, that was it! Thank you! Sorry for the noobness.